# Datatables buttons not showing except for CSV

Tags: jquery, html, button, datatables

I'm asking this after referring to few answers on similar problems but couldn't manage to get it done on mine.
I try my existing code which is successful for `CSV` & `COPY` buttons, but for the others, it's totally didn't show up as my expectation. Let me share my codes for review.

**jQUERY** 
Initialisation of Datatables

```
var table = $('#audit').DataTable({
  deferRender: true,
  responsive: true,
  pageLength: 10,
  ajax:{type: 'POST',
    url: 'audit_log_lib.php',
    data: function () { return $('#auditForm').serialize(); }
  },
  columnDefs: [{ "orderable": true, "targets": 4 }],
  order: [[0, 'desc']]
});
```

Initialisation for Buttons

```
var date = $.now();

new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
    buttons: [
    {extend:'csv', text: '<?php echo $xml_common->download.' CSV'; ?>', filename:'<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>_AuditTrail_'+date},
    {extend:'copy', text: '<?php echo $xml_common->download.' COPY'; ?>', filename:'<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>_AuditTrail_'+date},
    {extend:'excelHtml5', text: '<?php echo $xml_common->download.' Excel'; ?>', filename:'<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>_AuditTrail_'+date},
    {extend:'pdf', text: '<?php echo $xml_common->download.' PDF'; ?>', filename:'<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>_AuditTrail_'+date}
  ]
} );
table.buttons().container().appendTo('#export');
```

**Output**
[image: buttons export]

Before I forgot, here's the js plugin for initialise the buttons

> js/dataTables.buttons.min.js 
>  js/buttons.html5.min.js

As you can see at the image above, only `csv` and `copy` which appears its button while others are not. I also read some suggestions which advise to put 'B' in datatables `dom` and declare the buttons inside datatables initialisation but when I'm trying to do that, it will results in page loads bugs. I'm keen to know if did I missing something so far. Appreciated any helps to get me the way out of this bugs.

**UPDATE**
After adding js plugin `js/jszip.min.js`, the button for excel appears, but not for pdf. See this image:-
[image: excel button]

**UPDATE WITH WORKING SOLUTIONS**
After several research and attempts, I manage to solve this issues as you can see at the image below(Remove *Copy* button since it's not necessary for my task):-
[image: success button]
The solutions I got can be referred [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/910). I included these script tags

> js/pdfmake.min.js 
>  js/vfs_fonts.js

and it works now as image above.

Comment: I think you are missing some includes.

Comment: @Bindrid perhaps, but I'm really out of ideas on what it is. Even now, I'm still trying to figuring it out but try and error.

Comment: Why are you not following the examples on DataTables.net?

Comment: this one shows the basic initialization and all of the separate includes https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: for sure you are missing jszip.min.js

Comment: @Bindrid I use method `new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons();`. As an example in datatables, it'll return bugs on page loads.

Comment: @Bindrid I just update questions above. feel free to have a look. =)